# Unknown peer xxx, excluding from schema agreement check

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, datastax, datastax-java-driver

Since upgrading to Cassandra Java driver v4.x, we keep seeing the following messages in the client app logs:

```
[s1] Unknown peer xxx, excluding from schema agreement check
```

FWIW, `xxx` seems like a UUID, not an IP.

We are connecting to Azure Cosmos DB using the Cassandra Java driver v4.6.1.  The message seems to be emanating from [SchemaAgreementChecker](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/internal/core/metadata/SchemaAgreementChecker.java#L163), but it's pretty useless because it doesn't suggest any way to fix the supposed problem. After digging into the code, I think the problem is that the following query returns a new `host_id` each time it's executed.

```
SELECT host_id, schema_version FROM system.peers;
```

[SchemaAgreementChecker.java#L143](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/internal/core/metadata/SchemaAgreementChecker.java#L143)

It seems the driver is trying to match up the `host_id` received from peer gossip with the nodes received from `InternalDriverContext`. I'm not a Cassandra or Azure admin, so I'm not sure what the implication of this is, but given that this warning wasn't shown before, there's some assumption made in the code that isn't holding up.

Any ideas on what could be done here to get rid of this message?

Comment: Driver maintains a topology of C* cluster. If some host is newly added, driver might have not updated internal data structure (map) with new hostid. Once that is updated you should not see the issue. 

Are you adding / removing nodes to cluster frequently ? If this is the case this warning message should go away and you should not worry about it.

Comment: @ManishKhandelwal _Are you adding / removing nodes to cluster frequently?_ Not at all, if I did, this wouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: As you said that this query "SELECT host_id, schema_version FROM system.peers;" returns new host_id each time it is being executed, that made me think that you are adding new nodes. Host_id generally does not change till the node is removed and new are added.

Comment: @ManishKhandelwal That part is true, and the `host_id` seems like UUID, not IP, as I'd expect. How does a node get a `host_id`?

Comment: As Erick mentioned in answer that it is an issue is  with implementation and non compliance of Azure Cosmos DB. And regarding host id in Cassandra, it is always a UUID not an IP.

Comment: @ManishKhandelwal Eric's answer is vague on more than one counts. I'd like to "understand" the problem, not skirt around it.

Comment: Datastax driver is created to support Cassandra and in Cassandra host_id does not change unless you add a new host_id. So issue is with Azure implementation in which your host_id is changing too frequently.  There might be some changes/ additional checks in new code for driver which are causing the warning messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with Azure Cosmos DB which isn't a full implementation of Apache Cassandra but provides an CQL-like API.

The `SchemaAgreementChecker.java` class was added in Java driver 4.0 ([JAVA-1638](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1638)) and it seems like Azure Cosmos DB isn't fully compliant so try using Java driver 3.x and it should work. Cheers!

Comment: Well, as my question states, we upgraded to the newer driver, so downgrading isn’t an option. What do you mean by “_Azure Cosmos DB isn't fully compliant_”? What is missing?

Comment: Also, the ticket you linked to says "_Implement schema agreement like in 3.x_", so I'm finding it hard to believe that they just plucked this out of thin air. It was there in 3.x, just differently.